# How to fit text to a page horizontally?

Tags: notepad++

Is there a setting in Notepad++ to fit text to a page horizontally?

How  text is currently formatted:

[image]

Comment: Word wrapping? http://dineshkarur.blogspot.sg/2011/03/turn-onoff-word-wrap-in-notepad.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Is there a setting in Notepad++ to fit text to a page horizontally?

Menu > View > Wordwrap

Example Before:

[image]

Example After:

[image]